# Getting Memory metrics in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite, metrics

I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0. Actually now i am getting memory metrics by the following(Using Java thick client),

```
    ClusterGroup remoteGroup = ignite.cluster().forRemotes();
    ClusterMetrics metrics = remoteGroup.metrics();
```

Is there any way to get the Memory metrics by Python or Java thin client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported currently by thin clients, so you will have to gather this information using thick client or server node.

Then you can store it somewhere (in e.g. cache) to be accessible by thin clients too.

Comment: Is there any way to get metrics except using thick client? i need like script(python) programming

Comment: It is not possible at the moment, you can get them on server or thick client node.